# ASP.NET Core WebApi 201 response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-codes

I have code:

```
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Driver), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Create/{carrierId:int}")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdministrators")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int carrierId, DriverPersonalInfoCreateAPI model)
    {
        return await CreatePrivateAsync(carrierId, model);
    }

    private async Task<IActionResult> CreatePrivateAsync(int carrierId, DriverPersonalInfoCreateAPI model)
    {
        var driver = _mapper.Map<Driver>(model);
        //...

        var uri = new Uri($"{Utils.UrlBuilderWithoutQueryString(Request)}/api/Driver/get/{driver.Id}");
        return Created(uri, driver);
   }
```

But when I call it I get a result:

[image]

why so? I expect 201 response with Location header and json object as body

Comment: 1. Check whether the server is running and make sure it listens on `44373` to process `https` instead of `http`. 2. Insure the controller has an route attribute of `[Route("api/[controller]")]` or `[Route("api/driver")]` 3. If you still cannot make it, please post the complete code of your controller as well as the part how you configure the routes within startup.cs

Comment: In postman, you may need to turn off SSL cert verification under settings to allow the request to work to https on localhost.